# Why are some of the methods not shown in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out the possible methods/attributes of an Excel VBA object (what can go after [object].). For example, I can get a list after I type in `Application.`(as shown in the image)[image]

However, I found this list doesn't show all the possible choices. Say, `Application.IsNa()`, which is a valid command but isn't shown in the list. I'm trying to find a way within Excel VBA that shows me all the possible methods and attributes. (like `dir()` in python)

Comment: application.worksheetfunction.IsNa() should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the Excel formula functions. You can view the list of those by opening VBA, then press F2, then scroll down the Classes to `WorksheetFunction`. Click on that and you'll see hundreds of extra functions:

[image: Classes - WorksheetFunction]

An alternative way to view these is to type `Application.WorksheetFunction.` into the code editor:

[image]

These functions allow you to use the Excel formula functions within VBA. Here's an example:

[image]

The `.WorksheetFunction` part is optional.

You can also send arguments directly to these functions, using variables or hard-coded values:

[image]

Comment: Great solution! So essentially `Application` and `Application.WorkSheetFunction` is identical? I've been having this question for quite long. Seeing codes using both. @Robson

Comment: All the Excel functions are contained in `Application` and `Application.WorksheetFunction`, but `Application` also contains additional functions that aren't from the Excel formulas. For example: you can do `Application.ThisWorkbook.Name`. My advice would be to use `Application.WorksheetFunction` when you want to use a formula function (sum, vlookup, etc) within VBA, then just use `Application` for everything else (thisworkbook, version, activecell, etc).

Comment: Three reasons for that: (1) anyone reading the code will be able to immediately understand when a formula function is being used (2) the formula functions are listed when typing `Application.WorksheetFunction` (3) the number of parameters is displayed when using `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: I just want to point out that there are differences between using `WorkSheetFunction` and not using it. Using `WorkSheetFunction` will stop code execution if the function results in an error, whereas just using `Application.Function` will not stop the code and the error code will write to the variable so long as it is of **Variant** type. You could then use an `IsError()` check to see that. You can see better example in [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/application-vs-application-worksheetfunction.584913/post-2893787) answer. It's especially useful for the **Match** function.